# Find all odd functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(t+1)=f(t)+1$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=\frac{1}{t^2}f(t)$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Please help me to solve this example:

> Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, so that for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$ apply:
> $$f(-t)=-f(t)\text,$$
> $$f(t+1)=f(t)+1\text{, and}$$
> $$f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=\frac{1}{t^2}f(t)\text {, for } t\ne 0$$

Thank you very much for your help and your attention.

Comment: I think there is only one.

Comment: To start, consider $t=0$ in the first equation. Then for the natural numbers use the second.  Then for integers use the first.  Then for reciprocals of integers use the third.  Then extend to rationals (a little more complicated).  Irrationals may be harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $f(1-t)= f((-t)+1)=f(-t)+1=1-f(t)$.

Clearly , $f(0)=0, f(-1)=-1$. Choose $x\neq 0,-1$.

$$f(\frac{1}{x+1})=\frac{f(x+1)}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{f(x)+1}{(x+1)^2}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}f\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right) =f\left(1-\frac{x}{x+1}\right) & = 1-f\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\\ & = 1-f\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac1x}\right) \\ & =1-\frac{f(\frac1x+1)}{(\frac1x+1)^2} =1-\frac{\frac{f(x)}{x^2}+1}{(1+\frac1x)^2}\end{aligned}$$
Hence comparing we get $f(x)=x$ for all such $x\neq 0,-1$.

Comment: +1, though it might have been kind if you had finished by pointing out that by simplifying $1-\frac{\frac{f(x)}{x^2}+1}{(1+\frac1x)^2} = \dfrac{ 1+ 2x - f(x)}{(x+1)^2}$ to make the comparison easy

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=0$ in your first equation to find $f(0)$.

Use that, the second equation, and induction to find $f(t)$ for integers $t$.

Use that and the third equation to find $f(t)$ for reciprocals of the integers.

Use that and the second equation to find $f(t)$ for all rational numbers.

It looks like (I am not sure) the irrational numbers are then *not* defined by your equations. Given the value at one irrational number you could find values for many other, but not all, irrational numbers. See [Vitali sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) for clues how to handle that. Of course, if you know that $f$ is continuous, $f(t)$ will then be uniquely defined for all $t$.